# How does it know where my value is in memory?

Tags: variables, memory, memory-management, language-agnostic

When I write a program and tell it `int c=5`, it puts the value 5 into a little bit of it's memory, but how does it remember which one? The only way I could think of would be to have another bit of memory to tell it, but then it would have to remember where it kept that as well, so how does it remember where everything is?

Comment: I think it scribbles it down on a piece of paper. Just in case.

Comment: +1 for a damn fine first question... welcome to the fold :)

Comment: @skaffman Well said. It's hard to put yourself in the shoes of the absolute beginner and I think this is a question that really shows curiosity and thought...though I did laugh out loud at hacker's comment!

Comment: Yeap, definitely much better than usual "it's one big error please help ASAP".

Comment: @sharptooth Yeah, or that one guy who keeps posting Google Code Jam questions while watching TV and hoping for the best

Comment: **@John:** Once you have some basic programming proficiency, you can look in to how compilers work to get the detail on this. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler . The Crenshaw tutorial should be accessible to anyone with a basic working knowledge of any c-like language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are lots of good answers here, but they all seem to miss one important point that I think was the main thrust of the OP's question, so here goes.  I'm talking about compiled languages like C++, interpreted ones are much more complex.

When compiling your program, the compiler examines your code to find all the variables.  Some variables are going to be global (or static), and some are going to be local.  For the static variables, it assigns them fixed memory addresses.  These addresses are likely to be sequential, and they start at some specific value.  Due to the segmentation of memory on most architectures (and the virtual memory mechanisms), every application can (potentially) use the same memory addresses.  Thus, if we assume the memory space programs are allowed to use starts at 0 for our example, every program you compile will put the first global variable at location 0.  If that variable was 4 bytes, the next one would be at location 4, etc.  These won't conflict with other programs running on your system because they're actually being mapped to an arbitrary sequential section of memory at run time.  This is why it can assign a fixed address at compile time without worrying about hitting other programs.

For local variables, instead of being assigned a fixed address, they're assigned a fixed address relative to the stack pointer (which is usually a register).  When a function is called that allocates variables on the stack, the stack pointer is simply moved by the required number of bytes, creating a gap in the used bytes on the stack.  All the local variables are assigned fixed offsets to the stack pointer that put them into that gap.  Every time a local variable is used, the real memory address is calculated by adding the stack pointer and the offset (neglecting caching values in registers).  When the function returns, the stack pointer is reset to the way it was before the function was called, thus the entire stack frame including local variables is free to be overwritten by the next function call.

Comment: Nice job spotting the question in the question.

Comment: I considered mentioning this but didn't want to complicate the issue. Well, there it is.

Answer (score 13):

Your code gets compiled before execution, at that step your variable will be replaced by the actual reference of the space where the value will be stored.

This at least is the general principle. In reality it will be way more complecated, but still the same basic idea.

Comment: It's like the compile relabels every variable you have to a number representing an address in memory. So, 'c' becomes '0xdeadbeef' or whatever. Relabeling is OK to do for the same reason you can go through all of your source code and change the 'c' references to 'd' references and the program still does the same thing (assuming there wasn't already a variable 'd' defined!)

Answer (score 6):

read Variable (programming) - Memory allocation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(programming)#Memory_allocation

here is the text from the link (if you don't want to actually go there, but you are missing all the links within the text):

> The specifics of variable allocation
>   and the representation of their values
>   vary widely, both among programming
>   languages and among implementations of
>   a given language. Many language
>   implementations allocate space for
>   local variables, whose extent lasts
>   for a single function call on the call
>   stack, and whose memory is
>   automatically reclaimed when the
>   function returns. (More generally, in
>   name binding, the name of a variable
>   is bound to the address of some
>   particular block (contiguous sequence)
>   of bytes in memory, and operations on
>   the variable manipulate that block.
>   Referencing is more common for
>   variables whose values have large or
>   unknown sizes when the code is
>   compiled. Such variables reference the
>   location of the value instead of the
>   storing value itself, which is
>   allocated from a pool of memory called
>   the heap.
>
> Bound variables have values. A value,
>   however, is an abstraction, an idea;
>   in implementation, a value is
>   represented by some data object, which
>   is stored somewhere in computer
>   memory. The program, or the runtime
>   environment, must set aside memory for
>   each data object and, since memory is
>   finite, ensure that this memory is
>   yielded for reuse when the object is
>   no longer needed to represent some
>   variable's value.
>
> Objects allocated from the heap must
>   be reclaimed—especially when the
>   objects are no longer needed. In a
>   garbage-collected language (such as
>   C#, Java, and Lisp), the runtime
>   environment automatically reclaims
>   objects when extant variables can no
>   longer refer to them. In
>   non-garbage-collected languages, such
>   as C, the program (and the programmer)
>   must explicitly allocate memory, and
>   then later free it, to reclaim its
>   memory. Failure to do so leads to
>   memory leaks, in which the heap is
>   depleted as the program runs, risking
>   eventual failure from exhausting
>   available memory.
>
> When a variable refers to a data
>   structure created dynamically, some of
>   its components may be only indirectly
>   accessed through the variable. In such
>   circumstances, garbage collectors (or
>   analogous program features in
>   languages that lack garbage
>   collectors) must deal with a case
>   where only a portion of the memory
>   reachable from the variable needs to
>   be reclaimed

Comment: How long do you think it will take someone to follow the link you posted, paraphrase what it says with nice-looking formatting, and win him/herself the accepted answer?

Comment: They say it better than I could.

Comment: @Beska I'm a poster child for laziness here as I'm not going to do what I proposed as a  good solution even though other people (you, for starters) have stated that they would upvote such an effort! Heh.

Comment: @KM I think that article does better than I could, too. I was sort of poking fun at how the system here works sometimes :)

Answer (score 6):

There's a multi-step dance that turns `c = 5` into machine instructions to update a location in memory.

1. The compiler generates code in two parts.  There's the instruction part (load a register with the address of C; load a register with the literal 5; store).  And there's a data allocation part (leave 4 bytes of room at offset 0 for a variable known as "C").
2. A "linking loader" has to put this stuff into memory in a way that the OS will be able to run it.  The loader requests memory and the OS allocates some blocks of virtual memory.  The OS also maps the virtual memory to physical memory through an unrelated set of management mechanisms.
3. The loader puts the data page into one place and instruction part into another place.  Notice that the instructions use relative addresses (an offset of 0 into the data page).  The loader provides the actual location of the data page so that the instructions can resolve the real address.
4. When the actual "store" instruction is executed, the OS has to see if the referenced data page is actually in physical memory.  It may be in the swap file and have to get loaded into physical memory.  The virtual address being used is translated to a physical address of memory locations.

Answer (score 4):

It's built into the program.

Basically, when a program is compiled into machine language, it becomes a series of instructions. Some instructions have memory addresses built into them, and this is the "end of the chain", so to speak. The compiler decides where each variable will be and burns this information into the executable file. (Remember the compiler is a DIFFERENT program to the program you are writing; just concentrate on how your own program works for the moment.)

For example,

```
ADD [1A56], 15
```

might add 15 to the value at location 1A56. (This instruction would be encoded using some code that the processor understands, but I won't explain that.)

Now, other instructions let you use a "variable" memory address - a memory address that was itself loaded from some location. This is the basis of pointers in C. You certainly can't have an infinite chain of these, otherwise you would run out of memory.

I hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to phrase my response in very basic terminology. Please don't be insulted, I'm just not sure how proficient you already are and want to provide an answer acceptable to someone who could be a total beginner.

You aren't actually that far off in your assumption. The program you run your code through, usually called a compiler (or interpreter, depending on the language), keeps track of all the variables you use. You can think of your variables as a series of bins, and the individual pieces of data are kept inside these bins. The bins have labels on them, and when you build your source code into a program you can run, all of the labels are carried forward. The compiler takes care of this for you, so when you run the program, the proper things are fetched from their respective bin.

The variables you use are just another layer of labels. This makes things easier for you to keep track of. The way the variables are stored internally may have very complex or cryptic labels on them, but all you need to worry about is how you are referring to them in your code. Stay consistent, use good variable names, and keep track of what you're doing with your variables and the compiler/interpreter takes care of handling the low level tasks associated with that. This is a very simple, basic case of variable usage with memory.

Answer (score 1):

You should study pointers.

http://home.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch1x.htm

Comment: The question is about what does the compiler do with the pointers to declared variables, does it store them on variables? :) I think its turtles all the way down.

Answer (score 1):

Reduced to the bare metal, a variable lookup either reduces to an address that is some statically known offset to a base pointer held in a register (the stack pointer), or it is a constant address (global variable).

In an interpreted language, one register if often reserved to hold a pointer to a data structure (the "environment") that associates variable names with their current values.

Answer (score 1):

Computers ultimately only undertand on and off - which we conveniently abstract to binary.  This language is the basest level and is called machine language.  I'm not sure if this is folklore - but some programmers used to (or maybe still do) program directly in machine language.  Typing or reading in binary would be very cumbersome, which is why hexadecimal is often used to abbreviate the actual binary.

Because most of us are not savants, machine language is abstracted into assembly language.  Assemply is a very primitive language that directly controls memory.  There are a very limited number of commands (push/pop/add/goto), but these ultimately accomplish everything that is programmed.  Different machine architectures have different versions of assembly, but the gist is that there are a few dozen key memory registers (physically in the CPU) - in a x86 architecture they are EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, ...  These contain data or pointers that the CPU uses to figure out what to do next.  The CPU can only do 1 thing at a time and it uses these registers to figure out what to do next.  Computers seem to be able to do lots of things simultaneously because the CPU can process these instructions very quickly - (millions/billions instructions per second).  Of course, multi-core processors complicate things, but let's not go there...

Because most of us are not smart or accurate enough to program in assembly where you can easily crash the system, assembly is further abstracted into a 3rd generation language (3GL) - this is your C/C++/C#/Java etc...  When you tell one of these languages to put the integer value 5 in a variable, your instructions are stored in text; the assembler compiles your text into an assembly file (executable); when the program is executed, the program and its instructions are queued by the CPU, when it is show time for that specific line of code, it gets read in the the CPU register and processed.

The 'not smart enough' comments about the languages are a bit tongue-in-cheek.  Theoretically, the further you get away from zeros and ones to plain human language, the more quickly and efficiently you should be able to produce code.

Comment: To teach myself assembly in the stone age, I hand-coded the binary codes (on a 6502), then "poked" them from Basic-in-ROM.  And in the 80's, where I worked I sometimes had to boot some old HP machines by toggling a series of 16 switches to manually load the CPU registers, then press the "run" button.  Fortunately, that was only for a maintenance mode.

Answer (score 1):

There is an important flaw here that a few people make, which is assuming that all variables are stored in memory. Well, unless you count the CPU registers as memory, then this won't be completely right. Some compilers will optimize the generated code and if they can keep a variable stored in a register then some compilers will make use of this!
Then, of course, there's the complex matter of heap and stack memory. Local variables can be located in both! The preferred location would be in the stack, which is accessed way more often than the heap. This is the case for almost all local variables. Global variables are often part of the data segment of the final executable and tend to become part of the heap, although you can't release these global memory areas. But the heap is often used for on-the-fly allocations of new memory blocks, by *alloc*ating memory for them.

But with Global variables, the code will know exactly where they are and thus write their exact location in the code. (Well, their location from the beginning of the data segment anyways.) Register variables are located in the CPU and the compiler knows exactly which register, which is also just told to the code. Stack variables are located at an offset from the current stack pointer. This stack pointer will increase and decrease all the time, depending on the number of levels of procedures calling other procedures.
Only heap values are complex. When the application needs to store data on the heap, it needs a second variable to store it's address, otherwise it could lose track. This second variable is called a pointer and is located as global data or as part of the stack. (Or, on rare occasions, in the CPU registers.)

Oh, it's even a bit more complex than this, but already I can see some eyes rolling due to this information overkill. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Think of memory as a drawer into which you decide how to devide it according to your spontaneous needs.

When you declare a variable of type integer or any other type, the compiler or interpreter (whichever) allocates a memory address in its Data Segment (DS register in assembler) and reserves a certain amount of following addresses depending on your type's length in bit.

As per your question, an integer is 32 bits long, so, from one given address, let's say D003F8AC, the 32 bits following this address will be reserved for your declared integer.

On compile time, whereever you reference your variable, the generated assembler code will replace it with its DS address. So, when you get the value of your variable C, the processor queries the address D003F8AC and retrieves it.

Hope this helps, since you already have much answers. :-)